# Screen turns off with weird artifacts if any window except the terminal is open

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I've had this problem with my Macbook Pro 13'' 2017 (A1708) for around 2 years now and have been using it with an external monitor. Everything works fine except for its built-in screen.
[image: Screen without displaying anything, only with its backlight on]
When I turn on, the screen usually doesn't work correctly, it only displays white strips. Sometimes, it does work, but if I open any program that isn't the terminal, it flashes with some weird screen artifacts and turns off (The backlight can be seen, but there is nothing being displayed).

Here follow some images that illustrate what I just said about the screen turning off if I show any window that isn't the terminal:

[image: Terminal open with screen working, though with some artifacts on the top]
[image: Select browser window]
[image: Artifacts clearly being seen]
[image: Screen shuts off with green stripe]

The above images - i.e. going from image being dislpayed to green stripe and then black again - happen in the span of a tenth of a second.

The weirdest part is that if I open the terminal, hide every other window, then put the computer to sleep and turn it back on, the screen works again, though with the same limitation of not being able to display any other programs outside of the terminal.

I'd love to replace the screen but I'd like to be sure that this isn't a problem coming from a cable or something like that. I can clearly see there's something wrong with the screen, due to the artifacts such as the lines, but it makes very little sense to me why it would turn off selectively depending on the window being shown.

Any indications or suggestions as to if this is a recurring problem in MBP's? I've had a lot of trouble phrasing my situation in search queries around the web.

There's one more clue: if I make the font of the terminal larger, the screen will start to shut itself off even while only displaying the terminal.

Comment: You can try to check for GPU card activation/deactivation. Terminal does not use this, but many orher program  it (like Safari).